# Rails - Sharing DB and Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, architecture

I am building a series of Rails applications for different use cases, but they all are using the same database schema. All the migrations and models are created in the Main app. What is a common approach in Rails to reuse models in other apps in order not to duplicate code?

Comment: [Rails engines](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html)?

Comment: And is any other approaches ? What do you think of the solution described in this article http://hiltmon.com/blog/2013/10/14/rails-tricks-sharing-the-model/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking to do is called [Multitenancy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy). Its explanation and numerous ways of implementation aren't suited to a short SO answer, since there are many different use cases.

There are many guides that show you how to do this, though, and I've listed a couple starting points below.

- [Railscast - Multitenancy with PostgreSQL](http://railscasts.com/episodes/389-multitenancy-with-postgresql)
- [Railscast - Multitenancy with Scopes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/388-multitenancy-with-scopes)
- [Slideshow - Multitenancy with Rails](http://www.slideshare.net/tardate/multitenancy-with-rails)
- [Book - Multitenancy with Rails](https://leanpub.com/multi-tenancy-rails)

Alternatively, the [Acts As Tenant](https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant) gem will attempt to abstract this pain away from you (mostly).